# show alert then when click the alert, redirect to the specific controller with pass the parameter too

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I'm working with codeigniter and this is my current code:

```
function pesan()
{
    $rute_id = $this->input->post('rute_id');
    $namapemesan = $this->input->post('fullname');

    if ($namapemesan == "" || $namapemesan == null) 
    {
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var id = "<?php $rute_id ?>";
                alert("Error!");
                window.location.href="prepare_pesan/id";
            </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

and this is my prepare_pesan function

```
public function prepare_pesan($id)
{

}
```

When namapemesan == null, I can't see rute_id in my url. I think I misapplied the rute_id in my javascript. Any solution?

Comment: `But the code is not working`  In what way?..  I'm assuming you might have wanted -> `window.location.href="prepare_pesan" + id;`  But that's just guessing as you haven't said in what way it's not working.

Comment: i can't redirect to prepare_pesan function with parameter is from $rute_id, and the url just like this: http://localhost/project/user/user/prepare_pesan/

for ex:
i want my url become like this:
http://localhost/project/user/user/prepare_pesan/2

I think I misapplied the rute_id in my javascript. Can u help me pls?

Comment: Slight typo in my last one. -> `window.location.href="prepare_pesan/" + id`  you tried that?

Comment: yup, but still not working

Comment: `yup, but still not working`  Can't help, your not saying what `not working means`..   Unfortunately I don't have access to your machine & debugger, try and help me help you.

Comment: if redirect to this url: localhost/project/user/user/prepare_pesan it will shown an error "Missing argument 1 for User::prepare_pesan()"  and if i add the id manually example, like this: localhost/project/user/user/prepare_pesan/2 the code work perfectly. so i just want ask how to pass the id with javascript

Comment: So what does the code generated by you php inside the script tag look like.?

Comment: here: https://pastebin.com/Hn6EgMmJ

Comment: I think your miss-understanding me, PHP is a SERVER side rendered.   Your PHP will generated the HTML file,.  If you look at this generated HTML file inside your browsers debugger, what does it say.   Ideally your first line of the script tag should say `var id = "1"` if not your PHP is maybe not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.location.href="prepare_pesan/"+ id;

public function prepare_pesan($id = null)
{

}
```

And in this line you lack of echo

```
var id = "<?php echo $rute_id ?>";
```